# How to reference ID as param in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-browser

I have a node with internal `id` 35831. I run the following code in the Neo4J Browser:

`:params "id": 35831`

`match (t) where id(t) = $id return t`

Expected result: the node

Actual result: (no changes, no records)

Is this expected behavior or should I provide info about my neo4j version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Neo4j browser, when you set a numerical parameter its type is a float. See the result when you type `:params "id": 35831`, you should see `35831.0` as a value.

And that's why your query returns nothing...

But if you use this query `MATCH (n) WHERE id(n)=toInteger($id) RETURN n` it works !

FYI, this is only true for the browser, if you use the `cypher-shell`, it will works like you want :

```
neo4j> :param id 5
neo4j> MATCH (n) WHERE id(n)=$id RETURN n;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following syntax to set a parameter in the browser:

```
:param id => 1

....

{
  "id": 1
}
```

Then your query will work just fine:

```
 match (t) where id(t) = $id return t
```